# 'Invalid header value detected' when trying to fetch email with Zend_Mail_Storage_Imap

Tags: php, email, zend-framework

I am trying to receive emails with Zend_Mail_Storage_Imap but keep getting `'Invalid header value detected'` on some e mails.

I have located the header which is causing the crash to the following:

```
Content-Type: application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text;
    name="=?UTF-8?Q?cc-demo-minutes-2014-09-09_-_=c3=a5_detta_=c3=a4r_en_kopia?=
 =?UTF-8?Q?_av_det_vanliga_mellanslagsbefriade=2c_eller_mellanslagsl?=
 =?UTF-8?Q?=c3=b6sa=2c_namnet_som_b=c3=b6r_bli_en_l=c3=a5ng_harang_p?=
 =?UTF-8?Q?=c3=a5_flera_MIME-rader.odt?="
```

Although it's a ugly file name it should be a valid header as far as i understand. I've tried a couple of email validators and they all agree this is a valid header. Why does Zend throw this exception and how can I prevent it?

The code that causes the crash

```
$oMail = new Zend_Mail_Storage_Imap($aImapSettings);

foreach ($oMail as $iMessageNum => $oMessage) {
    if ($oMessage->isMultipart()) {
        // Multipart messages
        foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator($oMessage) as $oPart) { // <--crash

        } 
    }       
}
```

Stack trace

```
[07-Apr-2016 10:40:12 Europe/Stockholm] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Zend_Mail_Exception' with message 'Invalid header value detected' in /usr/local/zendsvr6/var/libraries/Zend_Framework_1/1.12.17/library/Zend/Mail/Header/HeaderValue.php:133
Stack trace:
#0 /usr/local/zendsvr6/var/libraries/Zend_Framework_1/1.12.17/library/Zend/Mail/Part.php(600): Zend_Mail_Header_HeaderValue::assertValid('application/vnd...')
#1 /usr/local/zendsvr6/var/libraries/Zend_Framework_1/1.12.17/library/Zend/Mail/Part.php(151): Zend_Mail_Part->_validateHeaders(Array)
#2 /usr/local/zendsvr6/var/libraries/Zend_Framework_1/1.12.17/library/Zend/Mail/Part.php(289): Zend_Mail_Part->__construct(Array)
#3 /usr/local/zendsvr6/var/libraries/Zend_Framework_1/1.12.17/library/Zend/Mail/Part.php(353): Zend_Mail_Part->_cacheContent()
#4 /usr/local/zendsvr6/var/libraries/Zend_Framework_1/1.12.17/library/Zend/Mail/Part.php(578): Zend_Mail_Part->countParts()
#5 /www/zendsvr6/website/application/app/exterior/email/AppMailReceiver.php(509): Zend_Mail_Part->rewind()
#6 /www/zendsvr6/website/applic in /usr/local/zendsvr6/var/libraries/Zend_Framework_1/1.12.17/library/Zend/Mail/Header/HeaderValue.php on line 133
```

I also found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35926128/zend-mail-header-headervalueisvalid-is-not-valid-with-special-characters) suggesting that changing internal_encoding would help. It did not solve the problem in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this solution will fix your issue but I believe so:

https://github.com/zendframework/zf1/pull/567

go to your library/Zend/Http/Client.php  file and apply following fix as mentioned in link above.

```
@@ -1592,6 +1592,11 @@ protected function _validateHeaderValue($value, $recurse = true)
             return;
         }

+        // Cast integers and floats to strings for purposes of header representation.
+        if (is_int($value) || is_float($value)) {
+            $value = (string) $value;
+        }
+
         if (! is_string($value) && (! is_object($value) || ! method_exists($value, '__toString'))) {
```